# Unable to get the expression of solution in DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve the 1D Diffusion equation for a sigmoidal function. However I cannot the expression of the solution

```
Dz = 0.5;
eqn = D[u[x, t], t] == Dz*D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
bc = {u[Infinity, t] == 1, u[-Infinity, t] == 0};
ic = {u[x, 0] == 1/(1 + Exp[-x])};
dsol = DSolve[{eqn, bc, ic}, u, {x, t}];
```

Am I missing certain specifications in DSolve ?

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica cannot handle `Infinity` as boundary condition.

Try numerical solution with suitable `inf`

```
Dz = 1/2;
inf = 10;
eqn = D[u[x, t], t] == Dz*D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
bc = {u[inf, t] == 1, u[-inf, t] == 0};
ic = {u[x, 0] == 1/(1 + Exp[-x])};
U = NDSolveValue[{eqn, bc, ic}, u, {x, -inf, inf}, {t, 0, 1}]
Plot3D[U[x, t], {x, -inf, inf}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: But I want the explicit expression of the solution as function of x and t.

Comment: Sorry I could only evaluate the numerical solution as interpolation function `U[x,t]`